# Linq - How to construct this query without the 'join' keyword?

Tags: linq, linq-to-sql

I have the following partial Linq query:

```
var query = from ri in RouteInstance
        join rir in RouteInstanceRules on ri.RouteInstanceID equals rir.RouteInstanceID
        join rl in RoutingLocation on rir.RoutingLocationID equals rl.RoutingLocationID
        join rlh in RoutingLocationHistory on rl.RoutingLocationID equals rlh.RoutingLocationID
        where rlh.RouteTakenTime >= new System.DateTime(2011,2,4) && rlh.RouteTakenTime <= new System.DateTime(2011,2,5)

There is a 1:M relationship between RouteInstance and RouteInstanceRules
There is a 1:M relationship between RouteInstanceRules and RoutingLocation
There is a 1:M relationship between RoutingLocation and RoutingLocationHistory
```

Since these relationships are enforced using FKs and are therefore known to L2S, I should be able to construct this query without using the 'join' keyword. But, I am stumped as to how to do it.

Thanks.

Comment: Is this what you are looking for ? http://blogs.msdn.com/b/charlie/archive/2007/02/20/one-to-many-and-joins.aspx from this article http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4133455/linq-join-confusion . Looks like you already posted comments there.

Comment: @Chris - I don't think this is quite the same, and I wasn't really happy with the answers I got to that question I posted. But thank you.

Comment: why do you prefer to not have the 'join'?

Comment: @Equiso - Because it shouldn't be necessary for me to tell L2S how to join the tables when it has all the information it needs to infer the join.

Comment: Sure it can infer the join of one level of relationship, but if you navigate multiple levels, at some point you will have to tell LINQ what path to take because you may have other tables that you don't want to join

Comment: @Equiso if all FKs are correctly specified, you shouldn't have to do joins in Linq to Sql

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want the RouteInstances in the end? If so:

```
var query = DataContext.RoutingLocationHistory
           .Where(rlh => rlh.RouteTakenTime >= new System.DateTime(2011,2,4) 
                        && rlh.RouteTakenTime <= new System.DateTime(2011,2,5))
           .Select(rlh => rlh.RoutingLocation.RouteInstanceRule.RouteInstance)
           .Distinct();
```

Answer (score 1):

i tested a scenario like yours and got the same results
you may select many without join, sth like:

```
var query = from ri in RouteInstance
            from rir in RouteInstanceRules 
            from   rl in        RoutingLocation
            from    rlh in RoutingLocationHistory 
             where    ri.RouteInstanceID ==    rir.RouteInstanceID &&
             rir.RoutingLocationID == rl.RoutingLocationID &&
             rl.RoutingLocationID == rlh.RoutingLocationID &&
             rlh.RouteTakenTime >= new System.DateTime(2011,2,4) && rlh.RouteTakenTime <= new System.DateTime(2011,2,5)
```

Comment: This really doesn't solve my problem. You are still telling L2S how to join the tables when it shouldn't be necessary to do that. L2S has all the information it needs to perform the join because of the FKs in place.

Answer (score 0):

Check for associations in the dbml designer.  If it noticed your foreign keys, it will create the associations automatically.  If not - you can add them yourself (even when the foreign key does not exist or is not enforced).

By querying the association property, you can hide your relationship details.

```
query =
  from ri in dataContext.RouteInstances
  from rir in ri.RouteInstanceRules
  from rl in rir.RoutingLocations
  from rlh in rl.RoutingLocationHistories
  where rlh.RouteTakenTime >= new System.DateTime(2011,2,4)
    && rlh.RouteTakenTime <= new System.DateTime(2011,2,5)
```

---

If you want similiar results to Guillaume86's answer, but without the distinct... then do this subquery'ing filter.

```
IQueryable<RouteInstance> query =
   from ri in dataContext.RouteInstances
   where ri.RouteInstanceRules
     .Any(rir => rir.RoutingLocations
       .Any(rl => rl.RoutingLocationHistories
         .Any(rlh => rlh.RouteTakenTime >= new System.DateTime(2011,2,4)
           && rlh.RouteTakenTime <= new System.DateTime(2011,2,5)
         )
       )
     )
   select ri;
```